# Angular7 : Export JSON data to CSV

Tags: angular, csv, angular7, export-to-csv

Below is example for exporting JSON to CSV:

```
import { Angular7Csv } from 'angular7-csv/Angular7-csv';

var data = [
 {
   name: "Test 1",
   age: 13,
   average: 8.2,
   approved: true,
   description: [{"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "UserID": "KG19932"}]
},
 {
   name: 'Test 2',
   age: 11,
   average: 8.2,
   approved: true,
   description: [{"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "UserID": "KG19932"}]

 },
 {
   name: 'Test 4',
   age: 10,
   average: 8.2,
   approved: true,
   description: [{"Status": "Pass", "TimeStamp": "2019-03-12 08:19:50", "UserID": "KG19932"}]
}
];

new Angular7Csv(data, 'My Report');
```

.csv file getting downloaded successfully but in Description column value getting as [object object]. I have tried JSON.stringify and JSON.Parse but no luck. Anyone has solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just stringfy the description

```
     data.forEach(x=>{
          x.description=JSON.stringify(x.description);
        });
     new Angular7Csv(data, 'My Report');
```

Answer (score 1):

For more precise output you can use this code as well

You can export from JSON to CSV using this simple code. This code solve the many basic issues like, problems with the separator, custom heading, skip empty column and add - in place of the empty data for a particular column. Refer this github link to solve all the issue regarding CSV export in Angular.

https://github.com/marvin-aroza/Angular-csv-export

Consider this as you JSON data

```
jsonData : any = [{
    name : 'Berlin',
    age : '45',
    country : 'Spain',
    phone : '896514326'
  },
  {
    name : 'Professor',
    age : '42',
    country : 'spain'
  },
  {
    name : 'Tokyo',
    age : '35',
    phone : '854668244'
  },
  {
    name : 'Helsinki',
    phone : '35863297'
  }];
```

You can download you csv using these functions

```
exportCsv() {
    this.downloadFile(this.jsonData);
  }

  downloadFile(data, filename = 'data') {
    let arrHeader = ["name", "age", "country", "phone"];
    let csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(data, arrHeader);
    console.log(csvData)
    let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff' + csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    let dwldLink = document.createElement("a");
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let isSafariBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1;
    if (isSafariBrowser) {  //if Safari open in new window to save file with random filename.
      dwldLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
    dwldLink.setAttribute("href", url);
    dwldLink.setAttribute("download", "sample.csv");
    dwldLink.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(dwldLink);
    dwldLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(dwldLink);
  }
```

And to edit the format of the CSV you can add this function

```
ConvertToCSV(objArray, headerList) {
    console.log(objArray);
    console.log(headerList);
    let array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    let str = '';
    let row = 'S.No,';

    let newHeaders = ["Name", "Age", "Country", "Phone"];

    for (let index in newHeaders) {
      row += newHeaders[index] + ',';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    str += row + '\r\n';
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let line = (i + 1) + '';
      for (let index in headerList) {
        let head = headerList[index];

        line += ',' + this.strRep(array[i][head]);
      }
      str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
  }
```

In case of values with comma, You can use this function to remove the comma and consider it as one single value

```
strRep(data) {
    if(typeof data == "string") {
      let newData = data.replace(/,/g, " ");
       return newData;
    }
    else if(typeof data == "undefined") {
      return "-";
    }
    else if(typeof data == "number") {
      return  data.toString();
    }
    else {
      return data;
    }
  }
```